# Haskell occurring error regarding show instance

Tags: haskell

```
data Expr = Var Char | Not Expr | And Expr Expr | Or Expr Expr deriving (Eq, Ord)


instance Show Expr where
    show (Var x) = [x]
    show (Not (Var y)) = "~"++ show (Var y)
    show (And (Var x) (Var y)) = show (Var x) ++ " ^ " ++ show (Var y)
    show ((Or (Var x) (Var y))) = show (Var x) ++ " v " ++ show (Var y)
    show (Not (Or (Var x) (Var y))) = "~(" ++ show (Or (Var x) (Var y)) ++ ")"
    show (And (Var x) (And (Var y) (Var z))) = show (Var x) ++ " ^ " ++ "(" ++ show (And (Var y) (Var z)) ++ ")"
```

I`m not sure exactly why i get this error when i run:

```
>(Not (Not (Var 'a')))
*** Exception: (21,5)-(26,112): Non-exhaustive patterns in function show
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: One example: `(Or (Var x) (And (Var y) (Var z)))` - and there will be many more. I think you will need a recursive fold to format this data structure as it itself is recursive

Comment: im not sure how to do that as i just stared using haskell

Comment: BTW, don't write `Show` instances like that. The result of `show` should always be syntactically valid Haskell code, but `~` doesn't work. (Though the rest could be ok, maybe just change `~` to `Neg` and implement the `∧` and `∨` operators. They must use the correct Unicode symbols then, not `^` and `v`.) If you want the result to be this custom pseudo-maths syntax, then instead make it a function `prettyShowExpr`.

Comment: `Not` can be applied to *any* expression, not just a `Var` value, so `show (Not expr) = "~" ++ show expr`, etc. You'll almost certainly have to insert parentheses into the result to express the grouping implicit in the AST. For example, `Not (And (Var 'x') (Var 'y'))` is not accurately represented with `"~x^y"`, but rather `"~(x^y)"`.

Answer (score 4):

An `And` can also contain another `And`, so for example `And (And (Var 'x') (Var 'y')) (Var 'z')`. In your `Show` instance you always assume that the parameters are `Var`s, that is not necessary.

You can implement the `Show` instance as:

```
instance Show Expr where
    show (Var x) = [x]
    show (Not x) = "~ ("++ show x ++ ")"
    show (And x y) = "(" ++ show x ++ " ^ " ++ show y ++ ")"
    show (Or x y) = "(" ++ show x ++ " v " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

This will introduce a lot of parenthesis. Therefore it is better to work with a precedence parameter. In fact the `Show` instance already has support for this: you can work with [**`showsPrec :: Int -> a -> String -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showsPrec). Here the `Int` parameter is the *operator precedence* of the outer context, and the first `String` parameter is the string that needs to be appended at the end: that is done for performance reasons.

We thus can implement this as:

```
instance Show Expr where
    showsPrec n (Var x) = (x :)
    showsPrec n (Not x) = showParen (n > 9) ( ('~' :) . showsPrec 10 x)
    showsPrec n (And x y) = showParen (n > 8) ((showsPrec 9 x) . (" ^ " ++) . showsPrec 9 y)
    showsPrec n (Or x y) = showParen (n > 7) ((showsPrec 8 x) . (" v " ++) . showsPrec 8 y)
```

Here we will show parenthesis for `not` if the outer countext has a precedence higher than `9`, and call the `showPrec` with a precence 10 such that the `showPrec` inside will not print extra parenthesis, unless it has a precedence of 10 or higher. The same applies for the other functions.

This thus means that we can print an expression with parenthesis like:

```
ghci> show (Not (And (Or (Not (Var 'x')) (Var 'y')) (Var 'z')))
"~((~x v y) ^ z)"
```

Here the `And … …` will thus print parenthesis since it is called with a precedence of nine, and the threshold is 8 to print parenthesis. But there are no brackets for around `~x`, since the threshold is lower than 10.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hard-coding lots of deep expressions, you should just pattern match on the topmost constructors and then recurse down.

```
instance Show Expr where
  show (Var v) = [v]
  show (Not x) = "Not ("++show x++")"
  show (And x y) = "(" ++ show x ++ ") ∧ (" ++ ...
  show (Or x y) = ...
```

Remember to implement the `∧` and `∨` operators if you mention them in the `show` results.

```
infixr 3 ∧
(∧) :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
(∧) = And
```

Actually it is preferred to *not* implement `show` when defining recursive-data `Show` instances, instead implement `showsPrec` which has a more sophisticated way of adding parentheses as needed.